# Associate Image with Attribute Option

Tags: magento2

This might be more of a conceptual question, but I'm trying to think of the best solution to associate an image with each attribute option.

Specifically: our products have a "manufacturers" attribute. I'd like to set up a way to add/remove images for each manufacturer option, so that I can display that manufacturer logo on the product page / pull it in as needed throughout the site.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can approach this:

1. Go the custom module way and create an extension that adds a column to the attribute table for image.
2. Use extensions such as [Amasty Shop by brand](https://amasty.com/shop-by-brand-for-magento-2.html) - it has a lot of features that you're not looking for but includes the capability to associate an attribute value with a brand

[image: amasty shop by brand]